# Is there better way to open vcf file from react native except Linking

Tags: android, ios, react-native, react-native-ios

When I try:

```
Linking.openURL("....vcf");
```

My app open browser and contacts with specified `vcf` is displayed.
Is there way to avoid this in react native and open `vcf` without moving to browser first?

Comment: what do you want to do after opening the vcf file?

Comment: Same like when I press it in browser. I just don’t want to open browser when click.

Comment: is it opening in another browser or in your own app

Comment: I want to open it without leaving my app. But it move to browser and open it there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use the following library [react-native-inappbrowser](https://github.com/proyecto26/react-native-inappbrowser)

follow the installation from the github page

```
import { Linking } from 'react-native'
import InAppBrowser from 'react-native-inappbrowser-reborn'

...
  async openLink() {
    try {
      const url = '...vcf'
      if (await InAppBrowser.isAvailable()) {
        const result = await InAppBrowser.open(url, {
          // iOS Properties
          dismissButtonStyle: 'cancel',
          preferredBarTintColor: '#453AA4',
          preferredControlTintColor: 'white',
          readerMode: false,
          animated: true,
          modalPresentationStyle: 'overFullScreen',
          modalTransitionStyle: 'partialCurl',
          modalEnabled: true,
          // Android Properties
          showTitle: true,
          toolbarColor: '#6200EE',
          secondaryToolbarColor: 'black',
          enableUrlBarHiding: true,
          enableDefaultShare: true,
          forceCloseOnRedirection: false,
          // Specify full animation resource identifier(package:anim/name)
          // or only resource name(in case of animation bundled with app).
          animations: {
            startEnter: 'slide_in_right',
            startExit: 'slide_out_left',
            endEnter: 'slide_in_left',
            endExit: 'slide_out_right'
          },
          headers: {
            'my-custom-header': 'my custom header value'
          },
          waitForRedirectDelay: 0
        })
        Alert.alert(JSON.stringify(result))
      }
      else Linking.openURL(url)
    } catch (error) {
      Alert.alert(error.message)
    }
  }
...
```

you can check [the example app here](https://github.com/proyecto26/react-native-inappbrowser/tree/master/example)

Answer (score 0):

The accepted solution above is like a 'bazooka for a cockraoch' imo.
Probably better for your app to just read the contents of the vcf file and render them yourself. Better than importing an entire browser.